# Save page content in specified period of time

Tags: php

What would be the best approach to automatically save a webpage content (source code) once in specified period of time, for example every hour. Now I use cron jobs and file_get_contents php function. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any better way to do that?

You have a working solution that can hardly be improved upon. Stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cURL - better security. Only slightly better solution